# vloopup multi key lookup in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have two sheets in my workbook.

First has two keys `id1` and `id2`

Second one has mapping from concatenated ids to value.

**Example**

First Table;

```
041       12    
042       3
```

Second Table;

```
04112       atp    
0423        wta
```

I want to fill the first table with the values in second table.

I am using this formula `=VLOOKUP(A1&B1, details!A2:B13, 2)`

This is not giving me the desired result.

When I  tried with the actual key, it worked `=VLOOKUP(04112, details!A2:B13, 2)`

I am not sure what mistake I am making when passing the key in `vlookup` function.

Comment: Remember the forth criterion.  `=VLOOKUP(A1&B1, details!A2:B13, 2,FALSE)`

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, can you give more information about the setup? `=VLOOKUP(A1&B1, details!A2:B13, 2)` looks like it should work in a clean spreadsheet